# Meaning of Angle Brackets?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

I'm reading an article on building point set surfaces ([paper is here](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/%7Emisha/Fall05/Papers/alexa01.pdf)).  It contains...

Step 1 of the projection procedure is a non-linear optimization
problem. By setting $q = r + tn$ for some $t ∈ \Re$, equation (1) above [not shown] can be rewritten as:
$$\sum_{i=0}^n\langle{n,p_i-r-tn}\rangle^2\theta(\Vert{p_i-r-tn}\Vert)$$
I don't know what the angle brackets mean.  Can anyone help?

Comment: In physics and some other fields they mean scalar product

Comment: $\langle u,v\rangle$ usually represents an inner product between $u$ and $v$, for whatever inner product is defined for your inner product space in which you are working.  The TeX commands here are `$\langle u, v\rangle$` to display $\langle u,v\rangle$.